# Unable to find an entry point warning when running MSBuild through TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm trying to setup a simple project in VS 2013.4 and have TFS build it for me.

I'm getting a warning message, and I can't figure out why. I don't get this error message when building straight from VS 2013.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\BuildInfo\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ReleaseManagement.BuildInfo.targets (147): Unable to find an entry point named 'git_commit_summary' in DLL 'git2-msvstfs'.
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to correct this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the warning were caused by upgraded Visual studio to 2013 update 4 on the build server, but forgetting to install the same upgrade for the TFS build server itself.

Comment: I have VS 2013 update 4 on both my dev machine and my TFS Build server. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that I'm running VS Professional on my dev machine but VS Community on my TFS Build machine?

Comment: Sorry, my wording was poor. In my case the build server needs Visual Studio installed. What caused the warning in my case was the following scenario: 1. Upgrade visual studio on build server to Update 4 (but not  TFS itself) 2. Warning appears. 3. Install the same update for TFS server 4. Warning goes away. It didn't have anything to do with the developer machines.

Comment: Thanks! We haven't upgraded to TFS Update 4 yet for a few reasons. I'll try that and see if it goes away.